# Get only some of the values from array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, attributes

I use code to retrieve values from database. The problem is that it shows all values. I just need two values and their names to show up. Values with name External and Visual

```
<?php $attributes = Custom_Post_Types::get_attributes(); ?>
<?php if ( ! empty( $attributes ) && is_array( $attributes ) && count(         $attributes ) > 0 ) : ?>

<?php foreach( $attributes as $key => $attribute ) : ?>  

                <dt><?php echo wp_kses( $attribute['name'], wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) ); ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo wp_kses( $attribute['value'], wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) ); ?></dd> 
<?php endforeach; ?>                 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: array_filter().  That or only query the database for the data you actually need rather than fetching it all and filtering it in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Then add a check for those two values.  See example code below:

```
<?php foreach( $attributes as $key => $attribute ) : ?>  
        <?php if ($attribute['name'] == 'External'  || $attribute['name'] == 'Visual'){
            <dt><?php echo wp_kses( $attribute['name'], wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) ); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo wp_kses( $attribute['value'], wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) ); ?></dd> 
         <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Does not work, with if. I supposed i was making an error in variables. I contacted the author of the template, and suggested me to use a function Inventor_Post_Types::get_metabox_field_value() . I still try. These are the functions

Comment: `public static function get_metabox_field_value( $metabox_id, $field_id, $post_id = null, $context = 'overview' ) {
  $field = cmb2_get_field( $metabox_id, $field_id );
  return self::get_field_value( $field->args, $post_id, $context );
 }

 /**
 public static function get_field_value( $field, $post_id = null, $context = 'overview' ) {
  if ( empty( $post_id ) ) {
   $post_id = get_the_ID();
  }

  $value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], true );

  if ( empty( $value ) && 0 !== strpos( $field['type'], 'taxonomy_' ) ) {
   return null;
  }`